# How to extract ports by IP address from nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I would like to collect ports by IP address from a list:

```py
_list = [
    [5, '255.255.255.0', 'dell', '744-1'],
    [6, '255.255.255.0', 'dell', '744-1'],
    [7, '255.255.255.1', 'amd', 'None'],
    [8, '255.255.255.1', 'amd', 'None']
    ]
```

The resulting list should be in this format:

```py
result_list = [['255.255.255.0', 5, 6], ['255.255.255.1', 7, 8]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? : )

Comment: Create different lists for each Ip, but _list can be much much bigger, so this is not good idea :)

Comment: Show the code you wrote

Comment: probably are better off with a `dict` with `ip` as key and the rest as values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most logical way to tackle this is to build a dictionary with the addresses as keys and the ports as a list of values. You could do this with an ordinary Python `dict`, but this is exactly the scenario where a `defaultdict` simplifies your logic, as it will either append to a list if one already exists for a key, or will create a new key:list pair and add the value to the list without you having to handle the create of new key:list pairs in code yourself.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for port, address, _, _ in _list:
    d[address].append(port)

out_list = [[k] + v for k, v in d.items()]
```

This first part of the code above collects all of your data in a `defaultdict` which has the contains the addresses as keys, and the ports as a list of values:

```
defaultdict(list, {'255.255.255.0': [5, 6], '255.255.255.1': [7, 8]})
```

If you evaluate your requirements, it's possibly that a dictionary will be able to satisfy them itself. You can reformat, however, reformat that to the list exactly as you specify in your question with a list comprehension:

```
[['255.255.255.0', 5, 6], ['255.255.255.1', 7, 8]]
```